# Statistical measures for data validation

Tags: binomial-distribution, sample-size, validation

I have to validate the data in one database by comparing it to data from a validated application system. The solution I came up with was (at least in theory) creating a statistical method that would define the number of random samples needed to check on a table of the database, in order to say, that with a 95% chance the number of errors is representative for that table. Then, with the probability of the errors I could consider if the data is valid or not.

The binomial distribution doesn't help, since I don't have any knowledge about the probability at which an error could be found. My statistical knowledge is pretty rusty and I can't figure it out right now.

Just to clarify again:
Given N the number of entries in a table I want to know what number n for random samples I have to chose in order to be able to say after testing, that the probability of the error is p, at a 95% accurateness.

I would be very helpful for every helping idea I could get. Any references to literature or sites covering this would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could work out (using the binomial distribution) the minimum sample size for which observing no errors will allow you to conclude that $p$ is less than a stipulated critical value $p_\mathrm{c}$ with 95% confidence. (It's approximately $\frac{3}{p_\mathrm{c}}$; see the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28statistics%29)) In any case a small trial study would give you an estimate of $p$ to use in deciding the sample size for a larger study. If the sample size looks like a large-ish fraction of the total no. records then use the hypergeometric distribution rather than the binomial. You might also need to consider whether the errors are independent, if you want to extend inference beyond the current version of this particular table.