# Sample size and confidence level to verify existing data

Tags: standard-deviation, sample-size, standard-error

I understand that to many this will be a frustratingly basic question which will not require much thought, but hopefully there are a few who can answer it anyway.

I have various sets of data on spreadsheets. Some worksheets have 900 rows of data and some have 15,000. There are many columns to each row, but essentially one row is one 'record'. The significant thing is that for each set of data, there is a finite and known population size.

I want to set up a 'checking' plan to provide me with a level of confidence (ideally without a tolerance, but if I have to have one then I have to have one). Each row (i.e. each record) on each worksheet can be correct or incorrect. There is no numerical variance, it is simply whether the data provided on each row accords to the various hard copy documents, data and calculations which feed into it.

My objective is to be able to state that I have reviewed the data and can say, with a given % confidence (and potentially tolerance, but ideally not), that the sample size I have examined (n) represents the larger population (N).

The ideal answer would provide me with a simple worked solution, but also a reference or several references to the genre of statistics that this exercise belongs in, so that I can go on to research it further and understand the basis for the worked solution provided.  I understand that I may be looking at a huge sample size, but I want to investigate the various possibilities, for instance to be able to work the formula (optimistic that one exists) backwards to determine what % confidence I could have with an *n* sample size.

EDIT:

I have a spreadsheet with 1000 rows on it. In each row there is an invoice number and an invoice value, just two columns. I want to know whether all 1000 rows are correct, but I don't want to check all 1000 rows manually. How would I calculated a sample size for this (say 20, 50 or 75?) and what confidence level could I have that all 1000 were correct, if for example I checked 20 invoices and all 20 were correct.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! A "level of confidence" in what? What does it mean to say the sample "represents the larger population" (or that it doesn't)? What's "tolerance"? A more concrete explanation of what you're trying to find out might help. It rather sounds as if you're interested in estimating the no. correct rows in the population from the no. correct rows in the sample, quantifying the uncertainty in that estimate, & coming up with a sampling scheme to limit that uncertainty to a required degree. (Please change the title too - it's not very informative.)

Comment: Hi - my objective is to be able to state that I have reviewed the data and can say, with a given % confidence (and potentially tolerance, but ideally not), that the sample size I have examined (n, i.e. the number of rows I have actually checked to be correct, or not) represents the larger population (N, i.e. the total number of rows in each data set). Hope that is clear?

Comment: Your comment just seems to restate what you said in the question, but I think the edit clarifies things. See [How to calculate a sample size for validating correct/incorrectness of records in a data table?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/139171/17230).

Comment: Thankyou. So in the link you have provided, if I want a 95% confidence level that there are zero invalid records in a population size of 1000, I would need to check 950? Assuming that is correct, if I were to required no more that 10 invalid records, what would the sample size be?

Comment: Set $K=11$ & find an $n^*$ such that $f(0)\approx 0.05$. ($f(0)$ is a monotonically decreasing function of $n^*$, an integer, so trial & error or bisection search are fine.)